# Result of 'AnimalListItemView' initializer is unused

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

It's been quite some time that I have coded in SwiftUI. I am kinda new in developing applications for recent version of iOS...

The warning lies in the #Preview of my AnimalListItemView.

```
import SwiftUI

struct AnimalListItemView: View {
    
    //let animals: [Animal] = Bundle.main.decode("animals.json")
    //let animal: [Animal] = Bundle.main.decode("animals.json")
    //let animal: Animal = Bundle.main.decode("animals.json")
    
      let animal: Animal
//
//    init(animal: Animal) {
//        self.animal = animal
//    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        //ForEach(0..<5) { _ in
            HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 16) {
                Image(animal.image)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .frame(width: 90, height: 90)
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12))
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                    Text("Lion")
                        .font(.title2)
                        .fontWeight(.heavy)
                        .foregroundStyle(.accent) //sets the accent color of the text
                    
                    Text("The worlds most social felines, lions room the savannas and grassland of the african continent , hunting cooperatively and raising cubs in pride.")
                        .font(.footnote)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.leading/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                        .lineLimit(2)
                        .padding(.trailing, 8)
                } //: VSTACK
            } //: HSTACK
        //} //: FOR LOOP
    }
}

#Preview {
    let animals: [Animal] = Bundle.main.decode("animal.json")
    //AnimalListItemView(animal: animals[1])
    AnimalListItemView(animal: animals[1])
}

//struct AnimalListItemView_Previws: PreviewProvider {
//    static let animals: [Animal] = Bundle.main.decode("animals.json")
//    
//    static var previews: some View {
//        AnimalListItemView(animal: animals[1])
//    }
//}`
```

It says:

> **Result of 'AnimalListItemView' initializer is unused**

Here is my AnimalModel.swift:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Animal: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let headline: String
    let description: String
    let link: String
    let image: String
    let gallery: [String]
    let fact: [String]
}
```

Anyone with some solution. I know its a silly question, but HELP!

Expecting for a solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must return `AnimalListItemView` value

```swift
#Preview {
    let animals: [Animal] = Bundle.main.decode("animal.json")
    return AnimalListItemView(animal: animals[1])
}
```